# Cloud SQL billing

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, billing

Its been my two months using GCP cloud sql. 1st month I got a invoice of INR1200. This month till date i have an estimated charge is INR 206. Though I have International SBI debit card, not able to connect because its saying Your card does not support automatic recurring payments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a finance question regarding a vendor.

Answer (score 0):

*user8104070*

First solution to your problem: Use a SBI Credit Card or any Other Credit Card. Debit Card is just an ad-hoc Solution to use on your GCP account.

Secondly, this is not the right platform for asking this types of questions. Next time try contacting the **Customer Support** or read **Google Official Documentation** for your problems.

Anyway, Happy to help!